# pick specific columns from multiple csv files in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, join

I am trying to create a modified CSV file from multiple small csv files. There is one column common in `field1.csv` and `field2.csv`. The final csv file `final.csv` will contain `column["NAME"]`, `column["ACC"]` from `field1.csv` and `column1["SCORE"]`, `column["TEAM"]` from `field2.csv` where `column["ID"]` from `field1.csv` is euqal to `column["ID"]` from `field2.csv`. If there is no value then it should be blank. I am using Python pandas.

field1.csv :-

```
"ID","NAME","ACC","POINT"
"123","TRR","OOP","64"
"124","DEE","OOP","78"
"125","EWR","PLO","98"
```

field2.csv :-

```
"ID","SCORE","TEAM","END"
"111","92","BCC","0"
"121","80","CSS","1"
"123","87","BCC","0"
```

final.csv :-

```
"NAME","ACC","SCORE","TEAM"
"TRR","OOP","87","BCC"
"DEE","OOP","",""
"EWR","PLO","",""
```

Python code that I am trying,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("field1.csv", index_col=[1], index_col=[2])

df2 = pd.read_csv("field2.csv", index_col=[1], index_col=[2])

finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2])

print(finaldf)

finaldf.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need one parameter `index_col` for convert first column to `index` with filter columns by `usecols` with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by default left join:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("field1.csv", index_col=[0], usecols=["ID","NAME","ACC"])

df2 = pd.read_csv("field2.csv", index_col=[0], usecols=["ID","SCORE","TEAM"])

finaldf = df1.join(df2)
print (finaldf)
    NAME  ACC  SCORE TEAM
ID                       
123  TRR  OOP   87.0  BCC
124  DEE  OOP    NaN  NaN
125  EWR  PLO    NaN  NaN
```

Another possible solution is filter columns before `join` by subsets:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("field1.csv", index_col=[0])

df2 = pd.read_csv("field2.csv", index_col=[0])

finaldf = df1[["NAME","ACC"]].join(df2[["SCORE","TEAM"]])
```

Last write to file with omit `index`:

```
finaldf.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: It works in this case. But, here all other columns will be joined except column[0] in both cases. But, I want to join specifically "NAME", "ACC" from fields1.csv and "SCORE", "TEAM" from field2.csv. If there are other columns then it should be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to add one more new blank column into final.csv, then what should be the way ? Let's Say new column name is "TEST_COLUMN"

Comment: Use `finaldf['TEST_COLUMN'] = ''` before `finaldf.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)`